How to restore funds accidentally sent to Gnosis Safe on a wrong chain?
Preliminary research
Help article: https://help.safe.global/en/articles/40812-i-sent-assets-to-a-safe-address-on-the-wrong-network-any-chance-to-recover

In case none of the above applies to you, please reach out to our dedicated Safe Discord, so we can investigate your case and potentially expand this article.

Joined Discord, it suggested contacting support via Intercom on the website, after chatting with an advisor he said "I'm not technical, ask devs here". Using a new account to (slightly) protect my privacy and not associate myself publicly with an embarrassing (and most likely irreversible) mistake.
Issue:
Safe creation transaction: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x7f4e288468fc6c87e0d9354b195fe8fe258ab95f3fca6b827e0bb5dee2677f47
OUCH transaction on Arbitrum: https://arbiscan.io/tx/0x4a2cf94df230df1d96e55cecdc3d3923806ea98dcb1b441a0bda0c4eebb5783b
(I haven't noticed until now due to mental model of “send to long term storage and forget”)
I have followed the instructions how to replay the creation transaction: https://www.loom.com/share/ca34aabcd62747fb9fb89bd463b4c741
The replay transaction on Arbitrum fails: https://arbiscan.io/tx/0x64192f4255e038b27ebe64eb66bd712d2e0152646e8c45f07526bde891638677
More detailed debugger view of that transaction: https://dashboard.tenderly.co/tx/arbitrum/0x64192f4255e038b27ebe64eb66bd712d2e0152646e8c45f07526bde891638677
Research
I have compared / diffed the bytecode of the 0x76e2cfc1f5fa8f6a5b3fc4c8f4788f0116861f9b that is labelled as Safe: Proxy Factory 1.1.1 on the Mainnet.
MISMATCH:

Mainnet: https://etherscan.io/address/0x76e2cfc1f5fa8f6a5b3fc4c8f4788f0116861f9b#code
Arbitrum: https://arbiscan.io/address/0x76e2cfc1f5fa8f6a5b3fc4c8f4788f0116861f9b#code

masterCopySAME:

https://etherscan.io/address/0x34CfAC646f301356fAa8B21e94227e3583Fe3F5F#code
https://arbiscan.io/address/0x34CfAC646f301356fAa8B21e94227e3583Fe3F5F#code


Realistically I estimate there is 1% chance of success. But maybe there is some hope?



https://arbiscan.io/address/0xec576a26335de1c360d2fc9a68cba6ba37af4a13
https://etherscan.io/address/0x5a98fcbea516cf06857215779fd812ca3bef1b32

Potentially useful piece of information with deployed chains and addresses: https://github.com/safe-global/safe-deployments/blob/main/src/assets/v1.1.1/proxy_factory.json
Maybe possible to redeploy using the same nonce: How is the address of an Ethereum contract computed? and article linked in one of the answers: https://medium.com/bitclave/how-we-sent-eth-to-the-wrong-address-and-successfully-recovered-them-2fc18e09d8f6
Related: a good discussion in the theme of addresses: https://forum.safe.global/t/how-can-a-safe-hold-asset-on-multiple-chains/2242

Because there is serious money on the on the line (around 6 ETH, around $18k at current prices) I'd be more than happy to offer 1 ETH bounty after successful recovery, I understand the time of experienced devs cost money, touching private keys of the deployer is a serious operation, we will need do it securely, I'm happy to fly to Berlin HQ and assemble the best White Hat Hacker Group, no hardforking though. If fail maybe "proof of error" and an airdrop, staring from Parity and their double $150m blunder LOL :)
FYI, I'm experienced StackOverflow user and I provided all the absolutely necessary information and I really hope that the entire question and provided info is entirely is on-topic 

Thank you for the detailed question, I understand this can be a stressful situation. We are looking into the issue, please hang tight as it may take a few days to have a definite answer.

Yeah, I tried to do my own research and followed the recommended steps. The matter is deeply technical and expertise is required. Thank you for acknowledging the question @Louis-SafeCoreTeam

Unfortunately, these funds won't be able to be recovered. The contracts deployed in v1.1.1 do not derive addresses the same way than more recent versions. The contract deployed at the Proxy Factory address on Arbitrum won't allow us to deploy a Safe on this network at the correct address.
This means that the control of your funds won't be able to be recovered.
I am sorry for your loss.
Louis

All good. That's what I thought. "proof of error" and an airdrop do you think this is a plausible idea? I have technical capacity to pull it off. I'm also looking for a job. I would be good at technical support - I know how to assists in cases like this - this detailed StackOverflow question is the better than any CV. I can even write my own job description: https://i.imgur.com/F9Ftr6c.png As you can imagine I'm in a position where I'd like to earn some money, generate income, have a stable reliable
